# Combinator Definition gives an error, unable to understand why

Tags: scala

I am trying to write a simple parser to be able to generate a DDL for an RDBMS, but got stuck in defining the combinator.

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._
object DocumentParser extends RegexParsers {
  override protected val whiteSpace = """(\s|//.*)+""".r //To include comments in what is regarded as white space, to be ignored
  case class DocumentAttribute(attributeName : String, attributeType : String)
  case class Document(documentName : String, documentAttributeList : List[DocumentAttribute])
  def document : Parser[Document]= "document" ~> documentName <~ "{" ~> attributeList <~ "}" ^^ {case n ~ l => Document(n, l)} //Here is where I get an error
  def documentName  : Parser[String] = """[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*""".r ^^ {_.toString}
  def attributeList : Parser[List[DocumentAttribute]] = repsep(attribute, ",")
  def attribute : Parser[DocumentAttribute] = attributeName ~ attributeType ^^ {case n ~ t => DocumentAttribute(n, t)}
  def attributeName : Parser[String] = """[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*""".r ^^ {_.toString}
  def attributeType : Parser[String] = """[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*""".r ^^ {_.toString}
}
```

It seems that I have defined it correctly. Is there something obvious I am missing or something fundamental about combinators I don't understand? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following code for `document`:

```
def document : Parser[Document]= "document" ~> documentName ~ ("{" ~> attributeList <~ "}") ^^ {case n ~ l => Document(n, l)}
```

Note the `~` after `documentName` and brackets around `"{" ~> attributeList <~ "}"`. Otherwise, all those `<~` and `~>` will discard everything except `attributeList`.

Basically, without any parentheses, the result is that everything to the right of the leftmost `<~` is discarded, and then everything to the left of the rightmost `~>` still remaining is discarded. For example:

```
def foo: Parser[String] = "a" ~> "b" ~> "c" ~ "d" <~ "e" ~> "f" <~ "g"
                         |<-discarded->|         | <-   discarded  -> |
```

With this change your code works:

```
scala> DocumentParser.document(new CharSequenceReader(
  """ document foo {bar baz, // comment 
    | qaz wsx}""".stripMargin))
res4: DocumentParser.ParseResult[DocumentParser.Document] = [2.10] parsed: Document(foo,List(DocumentAttribute(bar,baz), DocumentAttribute(qaz,wsx)))
```

Comment: Thanks! That explains why the parentheses are necessary. Everything works now. Actually, my code is slightly more involved; I need to either define the attribute directly or point it to another document's attribute (basically foreign keys). But I will try it things out myself first before posting any questions. Thanks again!